# Computing an agent on the further ends of cone of vision

Tags: netlogo

[image: Image1]

---

[image]
**Given:**

- The wall(grey agents) are in a constant place along the top of the
  world.
- The blue agents always directly below but at various
  distances. But they be off to the side of the gap but nevertheless
  can be rotated so that they face the gap.
- That the cone of vision angle is same for all blue turtles.

In the above figures, the blue agent's cone of vision is depicted. I wish to calculate the grey wall which meet the ends of the cone of vision ,that is, one on right and one on left.Also could I somehow calculate the x-coordinate at that point. Not the grey agent's coordinate as that would be a approximation.

**To Compute:**

The x coordinates where the extremes of cone of vision intersect grey turtles. Or those grey turtles they intersect.

**Rough Figure:**

So I wish to compute x_1 and x_2 in the below figure.
One way could as suggested by @JenB to divide it into three cases and and calculate A in each case.(Primarily on left or right). Then use trigonometry. I am correct. Are there any other ways as well?
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain why you want a non-trigonometry solution? By the way, A is calculated the same way for all cases, as is the length of the x offset. The only reason you need cases is to decide whether to add or subtract the offset from the xcor of the agent, and you can do that as a simple `if' at the end of the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following trigonometry approach(suggested by @JenB) works perfect:

```
 to-report calx2 [x0 y0 x1 y1 A]
      report x0 + (y1 - y0) * tan ( A + atan (x1 - x0) (y1 - y0))
    end

to start    
  ask turtles[
         set corner-1 list calx2  xcor ycor ([pxcor] of patch-goal)([pycor] of patch-goal - 0.4) (-45) ([pycor] of patch-goal - 0.4) 
         set corner-2 list calx2  xcor ycor ([pxcor] of patch-goal)([pycor] of patch-goal - 0.4) ( 45) ([pycor] of patch-goal - 0.4) 

    ]
```

The problem just arises when the left edge goes beyond 180 and right edge go beyond 0. I didn't consider that cases. Anyways, the above code solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a 2D problem, it is simply a case of intersecting lines.

I would avoid using multiple cases; that is very prone to errors.

You will have a line that describes your wall of turtles, and two lines that describe your FOV boundaries. You can formulate each of these three lines in parametric form as [o.x,o.y] + [v.x, v.y] * s, which is a fixed point [o.x,o.y] plus a normal vector [v.x,v.y] scaled by s.

The wall of turtles is only defined for a certain domain of 's'; let's say domain of wall.s = [0 to 0.4, and 0.6 to 1]

I would describe how to find the intersection points, but intersections of parametric 2D lines is pretty standard fare, and is better shown in a PDF, so I'll refer you to this...
http://www.ahinson.com/algorithms_general/Sections/Geometry/ParametricLineIntersection.pdf
(remember never to divide by zero)

Once you know the values of the scale parameters 'left.wall.s' and 'right.wall.s', you can tell whether the domain of the turtle wall is within the view of the player. Also you can determine the intersection points simply by plugging back into the parametric line formulas.

Comment: For example code for intersecting two lines in general in NetLogo, see Intersecting Lines Example and Intersecting Links Example (in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library). @Abhishek though, note that in your case one of the lines is horizontal. The math for that is simpler than the math for the general case, so starting from the general formula might not be the easiest path to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

dwn's answer covers computing the precise point of intersection.

You said you were also interested in just finding out what patch the answer lies on. Here's code for that:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1 [
    set heading -30 + random 60
  ]
  ask turtles [
    ;; show center of vision cone
    ask boundary-patch [ set pcolor red ]
    ;; show edges of 20 degree vision cone
    lt 10
    ask boundary-patch [ set pcolor blue ]
    rt 20
    ask boundary-patch [ set pcolor blue ]
    ;; restore turtle's original heading
    lt 10
  ]
end

;; answers the question, what patch on the top row of the
;; world is the turtle currently facing?

to-report boundary-patch  ;; turtle procedure
  let n 0
  while [true] [
    let target patch-ahead n
    if target = nobody or [pycor = max-pycor] of target [
      report target
    ]
    set n n + 1
  ]
end
```

Sample result:
[image: sample]

Of course, it would actually be computationally more efficient to compute the answer directly, via a formula. (With an optional rounding step at the end, depending on whether you want a point or a patch.) But this code shows how to do it without having to do any tricky math.

Comment: Thanks. Looks fine. But the problem is walls are turtles and not patches. And in my case I have considered patches to be quite large compared to size of walls(5 times). So turtles-on doesn't help either.

Comment: In that case, you must first compute the exact intersection point using trigonometry.

Comment: @SethTissue Yes. Check the new answer.